# Import/Export server error - Request Timeout

Tags: error, importexport

I am trying to export 'all products' csv and when I run the profile I'm getting an error.

The error is:

> **Request Timeout**
>
> This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you increased max_execution_time ?

Comment: You need to increase max_execution_time to avoid this timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

Oh. I kind of fixed this in Magento 2, the same code fix applies to Magento 1.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/1602

The core modifications brought a full product export from about 10 minutes down to 2 minutes.

The problem for me was that as the number of categories and attributes increased, the export function got remarkably slower due to an inefficiency in the php function `array_intersect`.

In `app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php` refactoring the uses of `array_intersect` to a combination of `array_combine` and `array_intersect_key` was the ticket.

See the Magento 2 pull request above for the exact modifications required.